# Comparison of 2 Queries

Tags: mysql, join

I am using MYSQL  version. 5.5.40.

Am using the following query to delete records from a table. The table has been indexed on the ssearchaccountid  and updated.

```
delete from ssearchesdata 
where id in (select ssearchesdataid 
from ssearchtermmap where ssearchaccountid = ? 
and updated between ? and ?)
```

If I replace it with, would it make any difference in performance:

```
DELETE FROM SSearchesData
USING SSearchTermMap
JOIN SSearchesData ON (SSearchesData.id = SSearchTermMap.sSearchesDataId)
WHERE sSearchAccountId = '200' 
AND updated BETWEEN '2014-10-24 00:00:00' AND '2014-10-25 23:59:59';
```

Comment: Those two queries are not equivalent.

Comment: It is possible that the mysql CBO could make your original snappy. How long does it take? Why not test it in a separate environment with same indexes. I am not one to recommend delete commands, unless they are boneheaded simple

Comment: off topic slightly, but don't use between.  23:59:59 is 1 second short of the full day use this form instead `and ( updated >= '2014-10-24 00:00:00' and updated < '2014-10-25 00:00:00' )`

Comment: DELETE FROM SSearchesData JOIN SSearchesData 
ON (SSearchesData.id = SSearchTermMap.sSearchesDataId)
WHERE sSearchAccountId = '200' 
AND updated BETWEEN '2014-10-24 00:00:00' AND '2014-10-25 23:59:59';
This query is the right query and is much faster performance wise than the traditional way. The dates used were for sample only.